# How to get exactly type of element in state machine diagram Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I want to find exactly type of element in StateMachine diagram (Initial State, Choice, EntryPoint, ExitPoint...) using EA.Automation interface. see the pictures below:

- [Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC5z6.png)
- [Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw15Q.png)

I used the code snippet below:

```
void GetRealTypeOfNodes(EA.Diagram diagram)
    {
        var objects = diagram.DiagramObjects;
        foreach(EA.DiagramObject obj in objects)
        {
            EA.Element elem = Repository.GetElementByID(obj.ElementID); 

            MessageLogger.log(elem.Type, obj.ObjectType.ToString(), elem.Name, obj.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
```

but what I get is:

- type of elements: "StateNode" - not as expected, Eg: Initial State or Choice

Could you help me to get what exactly I want?

Answer (score 2):

You need to inspect `Element.SubType`:

- 11 = decision
- 3 = initial

This might be documented somewhere in EA's help, or it might not. Issue the query

```
SELECT name, ntype FROM t_object
```

in the SQL scratch pad. This will return the `subType` in `ntype` and you can find out missing ones.

According to my Inside book, `StateNode`s can take the values 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 100 and 101 as `SubType`. But I have not listed, which is which.